# using str.find() to see if a particular letter is in a word

Tags: c++

I'm creating a hangman game for school.
The words to be guessed are pulled from a data file,
the program selects the last word from the file as the word to be used for the game,
'words' is the variable I used for this,
as the game goes, the user guesses a letter and if the letter is in the word it is correct and if not it is incorrect and the program displays a "board" or picture of the hangman progressively.

I used `str.find()` to see if the letter guessed is in the word, the code is as follows:

```
while (wrongGuess < 7){
    cout << "\nGuess a letter in the word: " << endl;
    cin >> guess;

    if (words.find(guess)==true){
        cout << "Correct! " << guess << " is FOUND in the word " << word << endl;
        continue;}
    else
        {cout << guess << " is NOT FOUND in the word " << endl;
        wrongGuess++;
        if(wrongGuess == 1)
            cout << board2;
        else if(wrongGuess == 2)
            cout << board3;
        else if(wrongGuess == 3)
            cout << board4;
        else if(wrongGuess == 4)
            cout << board5;
        else if(wrongGuess == 5)
            cout << board6;
        else if(wrongGuess == 6)
            cout << board7 << "\nSorry Game Over";
        }
```

The word that is used is `programming`.

My problem is sometimes when I enter a correct letter (like `r`) it tells me I'm right, other times I enter a different correct letter (`p`) and the program tells me I am wrong.

What do I have wrong?

Comment: `words.find(guess)==true` -- but string::find returns position, not a true/false...

Comment: Also consider using the "string the STL container" interface (with std::find) instead of the member function; that interface is more consistent with the rest of the language than string's flurry of member functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::basic_string::find` aka. `std::string::find` returns the position of the given character in the string, not a `bool`.

The code you've posted sometimes works because `true` decays to `1` and if the searched character is on position 1, the condition is true.

To fix it, you should do this:

```
...
if (words.find(guess)!=std::string::npos){
    ...
```

[std::basic_string::find](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find)

Answer (score 1):

Use [*`std::string::npos`*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/npos) to check th `find` result.

```
 if( words.find(guess) != std::string::npos)
 {
    //...
 }
 else
{
}
```